# How do i create infowindow with tab

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to create a table in infowindow to show that the first information and the second shows a photo gallery, also how do I expand the photo in table 2 in the event (on mouseover)

here is my code

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-8.759264,-63.906463),      
    icon:  predio
});

var contentimage =
    '<div style="width:470px;height:220px;margin:auto;float:left;"   /div>' +
    '<div>' + 
        '<img src="images/Sem título-2.png" width="440" height="190" />' + 
        '<a href="http://www.google.com.br" target="_blank">www.seusite.com.br/galeriadefotos</a>' + 
    '</div>';


var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentimage});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of an infoWindow is a DOM node like any other, for example:

```
var content = '<table><tr><td>1.1</td><td>1.2</td></tr><tr><td>2.1</td><td>2.2</td></tr></table>';
infoWindow.setContent(content);
infoWindow.open(map,marker);
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback.. but sorry I expressed myself badly, what I really want is a  infowindow with "tab" like in this exemple    http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_map10.htm

Comment: Your link is API V2. The API V3 does not have a tabbed infoWindow. If you want tabs in V3 you need to use a third party add-on like infoBubble: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/

Comment: got it bro, thanks for your help, also you know how to put facebook like button inside the infowindow.. appreciate..